# Do I need a server if I only want to upload data to a DB?

Tags: unity, server, webgl, databases

I'm currently creating a game where people get some kind of reports for their game performance on a website. Let's say, you log-in, play the game, the system gathers your performance data and this is being sent to a database so that it can be read and interpreted by an external website later. For this, I'm using a firebase real-time database and it's working fine by now.

I'm pretty noob with unity and I have read and watch tutorials on the internet where people actually create a **server** to achieve this but do I really need a server when the only thing I need to do is to post data to a database based on users?
This isn't really a multiplayer game, but there is some kind of information which is *shared* for example sometimes I need to get those data in order to get high scores and that kind of small information, but that's it.

I'm using unity webgl and firebase for the moment, and everything is working fine, but then why people always create a server for this?

PS: sorry for my bad english

Comment: Would you not call the machine that's currently hosting your database a "server"?

Comment: yes, but in the examples I've watched there is the database server and there is always a server build made in unity and stored in a dedicated server...  that's the reason for my confusion.

Comment: If "everything is working fine" then it sounds like the server you have is all you need for your case. What more do you want that you haven't been able to do with your current setup?

Comment: If you are using unity cant you use [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-SendingForm.html) to POST from your unity game to your [firebase HTTP  API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/) ?
AFAIK you are right, no server needed (only your cloud hosted DB with an HTTP API and unity acting as an http client or "user agent")